# How to create an unnamed window with tmuxinator?

Tags: tmuxinator

I want to create 2 windows with tmuxinator:

```
windows:
  - editor: vim
  - : # I want this window unnamed, but tmuxinator say that this is not valid
```

Thanks.

Comment: i don't know what tmuxinator is, but this sounds like `""` might work.

Comment: @hoijui thanks for your reply but "" will not create an unnamed window, it will create a window named ""

Comment: maybe an unnamed window is entirely invalid (as in, the windows manager does not allow it)? why do you want it unnamed in the first place? maybe there is a better way to do what you want. please explain.

Comment: @hoijui an unnamed window will be auto renamed by tmux, and this is useful when I run different programs in the same window, the window name will tell me what program is running. Finally I found a walkaround [see this page](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/292). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found this walkaround: 
https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/292

```
name: default
root: ~/
windows:
  - main:
    - tmux set-window-option -t1 automatic-rename on
    - clear
```